# Angular Material2 datepicker - dynamic formatting

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, angular-material2

I need to display dates in two different formats based on some user settings. 
 
Let's say `"YYYY-MM-DD"` and `"DD/MM/YYYY"`. 

I know that I have to write a custom `DateAdapter` (I've already done that), but is it possible to switch between the two formats with e.g. a dropdown list?

P.S. 
I'm also using Moment.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your custom date format is in a TS file.

This means you have access to Javascript and Typescript.

What you could do is use the localStorage to store the format, and in your date format :

```
export const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: localStorage.getItem('dateFormat'),
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: localStorage.getItem('dateFormat'),
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

I think you'll figure out how to store the formatin the local storage ;)

Comment: Thanks, it works! Have you got maybe an idea, how to do it without reloading the window? If no, I'll accept this answer as it definitely works.

Comment: To avoid reloading the window, you would need to rewrite the module where you declare your custom date adapter. I don't know how to do that, sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

Below you can see a custom adpater using the local storage. In this way, you don't have to reload the window.

```
import { MomentDateAdapter, MatMomentDateAdapterOptions } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
import { Moment } from "moment";
import { UserService } from "app/core/api/user.service";

export class CustomDateAdapter extends MomentDateAdapter {

    parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): Moment | null {
        let dateFormat: string | string[] = localStorage.getItem("dateFormat") || parseFormat;
        return super.parse(value, dateFormat);
    }

    format(date: Moment, displayFormat: string): string {
        let dateFormat: string | string[] = localStorage.getItem("dateFormat") || displayFormat;
        return super.format(date, dateFormat);
    }

}
```

And in your module:

```
....
import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatMomentDateModule, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { CustomDateAdapter } from 'app/material/custom-date-adapter';

....
providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS }
]})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Please notice that this example uses the momentjs implementation of the DateAdapter.